# Can we expect most of the safari freezing issues resolved after the Big Sur update?

Tags: safari, software-update, performance, big-sur

For the past couple of months, I have been dealing with a lot of issues with safari, most typically the constant freezing watching videos on youtube and on Netflix. For instance, when I consider pausing a video and it stays paused for a while and then getting back to the video to unpause, just to see the video isn't playing anymore. Currently, I am deciding between being patient and dealing with the freezing or taking it to the apple store. However, given the new Big Sur update is gonna bring big changes to safari, should I just be patient till September until the new update comes out or in other words, should I expect the Big Sur update resolve my freezing issue with safari?

Comment: Yes, you can expect, but only the update will tell.

Comment: What OS version are you running?

Comment: Whithout knowing what causes the issues you're experiencing, and without knowing whether these will be fixed by Big Sur, all answers will only be guesses.

Comment: If you want to look into these issues right now, please ask a new question specifically for one issue.

Comment: @benwiggy the new one, Catalina

Comment: @nohillside well all I am looking for is a bit of information just to ease my mind regarding the update as a potential resolution for the issues regarding safari.

Comment: Only Apple currently knows which (reported and un-reported) issues will be fixed in Big Sur. Even if they fix some stuff there is no way to know whether it will fix the behaviour you see.

Comment: @nohillside I mean safari freezing is a pretty common issue, so I'd assume that would be fixed with the new safari update.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is work out whether this is a known problem with the OS that's affecting all or a significant group of users, or a problem that is specific to your computer.

I have found this report, which details problems with video freezing:

https://mrmacintosh.com/2020-002-update-causes-some-macs-to-freeze-when-using-hw-accelerated-video/

though this suggests that the latest Mojave and Catalina updates should fix it.

There should be one more update to Catalina before the release of Big Sur. Brand new OS releases may fix old bugs, but they often bring new ones too, so you may have to choose between which bugs you want to keep. ;-)

If it's a problem specific to your computer, rather than a bug in the OS itself, then a new OS may have no effect at all, and you need to identify the cause of the problem by looking a crash logs, and testing in a new user account or in Safe boot mode.

You may want to try using a different web browser, though that may not help if it is a bug in the OS.